# self-cogenerator rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules

Let $\mathbb{U}$ be a non-empty set (class) of objects of a
category $C$. An object $B$ in $C$ is said to be cogenerated by
$\mathbb{U}$ or $\mathbb{U}$-cogenerated if, for every pair of
distinct morphisms $f, g : A \rightarrow B$ in $C$, there is a
morphism $h : B \rightarrow U$ with $U \in \mathbb{U}$ and $fh
\not= gh$. Then $\mathbb{U}$ is called a set (class) of
cogenerators for $B$. Also, an $R$-module is called a
self-cogenerator if it cogenerates all its factor modules.

Now, I want to know the following facts:

1. Are self-cogenerator rings  important? (When considering a ring as
   a module over itself).
2. Are there any characterization for them?
3. Do they contain any important classes of rings?
4. Are they important in commutative case?

Comment: I have seen cogenerator rings, but I haven't studied them thoroughly, and I'm not 100% sure if what I've seen is what you're describing. In *Lectures on modules and rings* you can read about rings that cogenerate their category of right modules, for example. Does this relate to 'self cogenerators'?  It sounds like maybe self-cogeneration is a weakening of right cogenerator rings?